# Kitchen sink examples of common languages for checking syntax theming

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I'm making a theme for VS Code and need to check the syntax highlighting. Is there anywhere that demonstrates all types (e.g. variables, punctuation, comments, functions, objects etc.) for the most popular languages? The code doesn't need to make sense or do anything, just demonstrate the syntax without errors.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such demo, from what I know. Best examples are the existing themes. The patterns used to describe a lexeme differ significantly between languages, so it would be hard to give a common example.

Since vscode uses/supports the TextMate themes you can however start with [TM's description](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) about the mapping between a lexem (a string, a number etc.) to identifiers, which in a second step are then translated to colors and font styles. Most theme writers use the xml style .tmtheme files format, while I find the JSON/YAML like style much better readable. See for example they syntax file I created: [antlr.json](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/syntaxes/antlr.json).

The file which defines the mapping between the lexeme ids and styling is then [here](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/themes/complete_dark.json). The theme file is independent of the syntax file and could be used for other syntaxes as well (and uses their assignment of lexems to the theming ids).

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I'm asking. I simply need code examples for the likes of C, JavaScript, Go, Python etc. that demonstrate the core aspects of each. I found this https://learnxinyminutes.com/ but each file contains a _lot_ of comments and makes the task rather tedious. I haven't been able to find such a site either. Maybe I'll make one. Thanks for replying though.